# Docker nextjs para desarrollo

Tags: docker, docker-compose, next.js

necesito ayuda para crear un docker-compose.

actualmente cuento con estos archivos:

.dockerignore:

```
node_modules/

Dockerfile

.git

.dockerignore

.gitignore
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:20.11.1-alpine3.19

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD npm run dev
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  backoffice-develop:
    container_name: backoffice_develop
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Esta es mi estructura de carpetas:

[image: Estructura de carpetas]

La cuestion es la siguiente.

quiero tener un volumen para poder editar el codigo desde vscode y ver el cambio reflejado en la web levantada por docker.

Esta es una aplicación NextJS.

todo mi codigo esta en la carpeta src.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para montar un directorio de tu proyecto dentro del contenedor de manera que los cambios se reflejen en tiempo real sin necesidad de ejecutar `docker-compose up` después de cada modificación, sigue estos pasos:

1. Modifica el `docker-compose.yaml`, para que quede de esta manera:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  backoffice-develop:
    container_name: backoffice_develop
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/home/node/app
```

Estamos montando la carpeta `src` de tu proyecto dentro del contenedor. En el contenedor, esta carpeta se montará en el directorio `/home/node/app`.

2. Ejecuta `docker-compose` de esta manera. Esto permitirá que los cambios se actualicen en tiempo real y que el contenedor se ejecute en segundo plano.

```
docker-compose up --no-recreate -d
```

3. Para ingresar al contenedor, ejecuta estos comandos:

```
docker ps 
                        
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                    COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                            PORTS                                                        NAMES
160f43085c35   xllauca/pee-clinica-odontologica:1.0.0   "java -jar clinica-o…"   26 minutes ago   Up 4 seconds                      0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp                    clinica-odontologica
```

Copia el `ID del contenedor`, en este caso es `160f43085c35`, y luego ejecuta esto:

```
docker exec -it 160f43085c35  sh
sh-4.4#
```

Una vez dentro, podrás verificar accediendo al directorio que especificaste para ser montado dentro del contenedor.

**Nota:** El montaje de la carpeta del host en el contenedor permite una sincronización bidireccional, lo que significa que cualquier modificación realizada tanto en el host como dentro del contenedor se reflejará automáticamente en ambas ubicaciones.